# Using monolog loggly handler in Symfony

Tags: symfony, monolog, loggly

I'm trying to use the Monolog Loggly handler in Symfony2 but can't get it to work:

```
# config.yml
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:  stream
            token: my-loggly-token
            level: info
            handler: loggly
            tag: symfony-app
```

I've removed the monolog entries from `config_dev.yml` and `config_prod.yml` so the the setup above isn't being overridden. Inside a controller I'm trying to trigger an info event, but it's not appearing in Loggly. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use type: loggly instead of stream.

```
# config.yml
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: loggly
            token: my-loggly-token
            level: info
            tag: symfony-app
```

Comment: I know its long time ago, but it does not work for me. I see no logs in loggly.